# Parent window and child window

Tags: cocoa

HI,
I m new in cocoa,
Im working in a project which is developed by other team and now I hv to work in this project.

I m displaying some data in tableview. and I am creating buttons for executing some action in a column of this tableview. I m using all this by coding.
that tableview is inside and an custom view.
from that button in the tableview I m executing a some code and trying to display a window that should works as a child window of that custom view.
when I m trying to close the child window the parent window also being closed.

I m using the following code for displaying the child window.

```
[[[self view] window] addChildWindow:childWindowOutlet ordered:NSWindowAbove];
[childWindowOutlet setMovableByWindowBackground:YES];
```

please help me for the following....
The child window should movable with parent window.
when I closed child window the parent window should not be closed.
The main window should not be accessible if the child window is opened.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like you want a sheet, not a child window

Comment: some kind of modal window, anyway.